# Proxmox 5.x vzdump-qemu.vma.gz to VMWARE or VirtualBox convert

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, proxmox, vmdk

How can I convert from Proxmox 5.x vzdump qemu virtual machine image to VMWARE or VirtualBox?

I want to run the Virtual Machine what is created in Proxmox (KVM + Qemu maybe) in VMWARE ESXi or in VirtualBox.

I tried to use qemu-img convert a.vma -O a.vmdk but made a not vaild format.
Seems like need other tool or parameters.
Also I have running Proxmox to export if needed.

If you can help, how convert Proxmox's VMA ( https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/VMA ) backup ( https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Backup_and_Restore ) to raw image, then to vmdk.

Thank you,
FA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently working on VMWare virtualization; I am trying to make a converted image from qcow2 to vmdk work with ESXi Server 6.0.

I used the image converter tool qemu with the following command

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 imagediskname.qcow2 -O vmdk myNewImage.vmdk
```

This command gives me a vmdk image which is only VMWare Workstation compatible. Therefore, in order to make it ESXi compatible I have to use the vmkfstools with the following command.

```
vmkfstools -i imagediskname.vmdk outputName.vmdk -d thin

qemu-img convert -p -f vmdk -O imagediskname-disk1.vmdk imagediskname.qcow2
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked.